# Why differrent session ids are generated after logging out from multiple tabs?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, csrf, session-management

I am using Spring security in my application. I just came across one very specific issue. When I am using multiple tabs and if I log out from all the tabs sequentially. Each page has new sessionid values (fiddler shows new session id for each login page request). This is causing issues since only the latest login page works and all others show sessionid mismatch error.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: @Lucas CSRF token is not the same thing as sessionid. aProgrammer, can you verify which you are referring to?

Comment: @AviD because the body had several times CSRF token but not session ID. So I assumed it was CSRF he meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you logout, the server will kill your current session, and create a new one. This new session is of course represented by a different sessionid.

Thus, the second time you hit the logout link, you got a login page with a new sessionid.

If you were to then refresh the 1st tab, after logging out the 2nd tab, you would likely have the proper sessionid, and be able to log in from there.

Comment: Is there no way other than refreshing the page ? I have already done that but that seems awkward. I was wondering how google / SE have handled that.

Comment: @aProgrammer if you are indeed referring to the sessionId, and nothing to do with CSRF (or am I wrong?), there are other ways around it, such as a sessionless login form, or cookie-based session ids only. Though perhaps you are in fact putting a CSRF token in the login form, which of course would not work for 2 tabs in parallel, let alone wrong sessions?